# need some help figuring out how to approach this validation

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for my form validation.  I have two select fields named parent_male and parent_female.  I would like to have a validation callback to check both the parent_male and parent_female in my database to see if it exists.  I already have a previous callback function that does just that, but with only one field.  I would like to check the two field values against the database, except I am not sure how to approach this idea.  Any help/ideas are greatly appreciate!  Thank you.

-Rich

Comment: Soo what happens if you have two dads?

Comment: Daz, unless you're talking about legal guardians, that isn't possible.

Comment: LOL, the parents are for livestock not humans ;-)  The only idea I can think of is attach a callback to one of the fields and use a post to grab the value of the second select field.

Comment: May be I'm missing something but... Why you can't use the same function for both fields?

Comment: I was not sure what I was thinking.  I have a tendency of making things harder then what they should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your callback as:

```
function isparent($parent) {
    $result = FALSE;
    /* do your stuff to check $parent is a valid parent and then ... */

    return $result;
}
```

and the rules can be set as

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('parent_male', 'Male parent', 'callback_isparent');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('parent_female', 'Female parent', 'callback_isparent');
```

In that way you use the same callback for both fields.

Comment: I am most likely wrong when I say this.  I thought using the the same call back for fields on the same form will not work as expected.  What I mean is, lets say one field returns false then you check the second field against the same callback it will always return false since the callback previously returned false.